# CMD IF statements

Tags: if-statement, cmd, set

I want to check whether or not variable h="yes" or h="no" and my code is obviously incorrect. how could i fix it?

```
@echo what is your statement (YES/NO)?

 set /p h=

 if %h% EQ 'yes' goto YES

 if %h% EQ 'no' goto NO

:YES

@echo you chose YES

 pause > nul

goto END


:NO

@echo you chose NO

 pause > nul

:END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little chages are neccessary:

```
@echo off 
echo what is your statement (YES/NO)?
set /p h=
if /i '%h%' == 'yes' goto YES
if /i '%h%' == 'no' goto NO
echo wrong input
goto END

:YES
echo you chose YES
pause > nul
goto END

:NO
echo you chose NO
 pause > nul
:END
```

- the correct syntax for "is equal to" is: EQU or ==
- `if /i` makes it case-insensitive, so you can enter yes, YES, Yes or yEs
- I added two lines for wrong input

Comment: Thanks, trying to get a better understand of this. And if you have time (I don't know if you'll see this but).
I need to enter letter into program, to do filter command, but there's results that are both in lower case letter and upper case letters, so if I type lower case letter it'll only give me results with lower case letter.

Comment: "


 set /p y=                        
(new line)

 tasklist | findstr ^^%y%"

Comment: `findstr` uses also the parameter `/i` to ignore upper/lower-case.

Comment: This solution will not work as written unless the person includes the single-quotes in their answer.  You can fix that by using `if /i '%h%' == 'yes' goto YES`.  CMD does its variable expansion quite literally.

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked to whittle my response down.

I think this what you are looking for which is something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

CHOICE /C YN /M "DO YOU WANT TO RESTART APACHE TOMCAT WEB SERVICE?"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 GOTO END

ECHO DO OTHER STUFF HERE

:END
ECHO YOU PRESSED N OR SCRIPT HAS FINISHED
EXIT
```